# Creating Array Type at runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, types, reflection.emit

I want to get 'array type' of a type at run time. I do not need the instance of the array, just Type. I currently use the below method.

```
    private Type GetArrayType(Type elementType)
    {
        return Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 0).GetType();
    }
```

Is there any better solution without creating the instance of the array?

Note: I cannot use `Type.GetType(elementType.FullName + "[]")` because I create the element Type at runtime by `Reflection.Emit`. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) it requires dynamic assembly to be saved on disk which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Type.MakeArrayType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc2e4ft8.aspx).

> Returns a Type object representing a one-dimensional array of the
>   current type, with a lower bound of zero.

```
private Type GetArrayType(Type elementType)
{
    return elementType.MakeArrayType();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I need a rest... I cannot tell how I got lost in static methods of Array and Type and never thought about instance methods (:

Comment: I agree that some of the choices on those types of making methods instance/static are quite perplexing.